# how to insert column to a model.matrix

Tags: r, model.matrix

I want insert two variables into a model.matrix, but I don't know how to do that

```
> k<-model.matrix(m2)
> dim(k)
```

[1] 475  28

```
k$township72<-rep(0,475)
Warning message:
In k$township72 <- rep(0, 475) : Coercing LHS to a list
```

Comment: Try replacing `$` with `[` ie. `k[,'township72'] <- rep(0,475)` or may be use `cbind` i..e  `cbind(k, township72=rep(0,475))`

Comment: Still not working"> k[,'township72']<-rep(0,475)
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, , "township72", value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  : 
  subscript out of bounds"

Comment: Try the `cbind`, it should work.  It worked with an example I created